# Computing Darboux Sums

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

Let $f : [0,1] → R$ be defined by $f(x) := x^3$ and let $P :=$ {$0,0.1,0.4,1$}. 
Compute $L(P, f)$ and
$U ( P, f )$ .
(Notation meaning the upper and lower Darboux Sums)

Comment: This is so easy to compute them just using the definition of such sums, and the fact that you're dealing with a monotone function ($\inf$ is attained in the beginning of the interval, $\sup$ in the end) - perhaps, you can try doing it yourself now?

Comment: In class we went over an example where the delta $x_i$ remained the same so we could pull out a constant and then add up the sum. What would this case be since the partitions are not equal each time?

Comment: You have just 4 entries in the sum: find the lowest value, multiply by the partition interval length, add to previous result etc.

Comment: L(p,f) = (0.1)(0)+(0.3)(0.1)+(0.6)(0.4) correct?

Comment: Are you computing $x^3$?

Comment: so it would be (0.1)(0)+(0.3)(0.001)+(0.6)(0.064)?

Comment: Yes ${{{}}}{{{}}}$

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how what you've typed is a partition but my answer below applies in general (perhaps the $P$ you've written down is the set of differences so the set of partition points is $\{0,1,5,6\}$ but then this isn't a partition of $[0,1]$; rather it's a partition of $[0,6]$ ...):

The function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is monotonically increasing. Prove that for any such monotonically increasing function, and any partition $P=0=x_0<\cdots<x_n=1$, we have:

$L(P,f)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(x_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)$

$U(P,f)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)(x_{i}-x_{i-1})$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't understand your concern about partition: OP wrote $\{0,0.1,0.4,1\}$ which is an appropriate partition of $[0,1]$, isn't it?

Comment: @Ilya I thought that the points of a partition of $[0,1]$ must be elements of $[0,1]$ (i.e., a partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ is a sequence $0=x_0<\cdots<x_n=1$). If this isn't the definition of a partition, then could you please tell me the correct definition? (I learned about Riemann-Darboux integration from Rudin's textbook where this was the definition adapted.)

Comment: @Ilya Oops! Now, I see that the partition is $\{0, \bf{0.1}, \bf{0.4}, 1\}$. I didn't notice the decimal points; I thought they were commas.